# SharePoint Online REST by using access_token still getting 403

Tags: rest, access-token, sharepoint-online

following this article http://www.ktskumar.com/2017/01/access-sharepoint-online-using-postman/
I was able to register an app and get a client_id as well as a security token.

Now if I follow the article, I'm able to get an access token by using Postman, SOAP UI as well as by using a REST client in browser. I'm also able to fetch data from SharePoint using this token.

However, I need to do this from a unix based middleware, which is able to do HTTP calls as well. I tried everything but I can't get it work.

Preparation that has been done before:

1. register new app by using https://.sharepoint.com/sites//_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx
2. add app and permission to site collection to grant access by using https://.sharepoint.com/sites//_layouts/15/appinv.aspx

After this, I do some webservice calls like this

1. I try to get an access token by calling https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/<mytenant_id>/tokens/OAuth/2 and got one. I can use this token in every REST client as well as in Postman. So I assume it is a valid one.
2. Now I try to retrieve the Title of web by calling this URL https://<my_tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site_collection>/_api/web?$select=Title

This always returns a 403 but only when using middleware system. If I do the same from any other client, it works.

Could someone please enlight me what is going wrong here?

This is how the request header looks like (I've shorten some things)

```
cookie'='fpc=...some other stuff; domain=.accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
x-ms-gateway-slice=prod; path=/; SameSite=None; secure; HttpOnly
stsservicecookie=ests; path=/; SameSite=None; secure; HttpOnly'

  'User-Agent'='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0'
  'accept'='application/json;odata=verbose'
  'Authorization'='Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbG... lot following here, but only value of access_token'
```

This is what the response looks like:

```
'RESPONSE_HTTP_HEADER_X-ASPNET-VERSION'='4.0.30319'
  'RESPONSE_HTTP_HEADER_LAST-MODIFIED'='Tue, 23 Jun 2020 08:10:42 GMT'
  'RESPONSE_HTTP_HEADER_X-SHAREPOINTHEALTHSCORE'='1'
  'RESPONSE_HTTP_HEADER_X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_RETURN_URL'='https://<mytenant>.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/error.aspx'
  'RESPONSE_HTTP_HEADER_CACHE-CONTROL'='private, max-age=0'
  'RESPONSE_HTTP_DATA'='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><m:code>-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException</m:code><m:message xml:lang="en-US">Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.</m:message></m:error>'
  'RESPONSE_HTTP_HEADER_X-POWERED-BY'='ASP.NET'
  'RESPONSE_HTTP_HEADER_DATE'='Tue, 23 Jun 2020 08:10:42 GMT'
  'RESPONSE_HTTP_STATUSLINE'='Forbidden'
  'RESPONSE_HTTP_HEADER_EXPIRES'='Mon, 08 Jun 2020 08:10:42 GMT'
  'RESPONSE_HTTP_HEADER_CONTENT-SECURITY-POLICY'='frame-ancestors 'self' teams.microsoft.com *.teams.microsoft.com *.skype.com *.teams.microsoft.us local.teams.office.com;'
  'RESPONSE_HTTP_HEADER_MICROSOFTSHAREPOINTTEAMSERVICES'='16.0.0.20203'
  'RESPONSE_HTTP_HEADER_X-MSDAVEXT_ERROR'='917656; Access+denied.+Before+opening+files+in+this+location%2c+you+must+first+browse+to+the+web+site+and+select+the+option+to+login+automatically.'
  'RESPONSE_HTTP_HEADER_SPREQUESTGUID'='78265f9f-40b3-b000-f2bb-2df685280534'
  'RESPONSE_HTTP_HEADER_STRICT-TRANSPORT-SECURITY'='max-age=31536000'
  'RESPONSE_HTTP_HEADER_TRANSFER-ENCODING'='chunked'
  'RESPONSE_HTTP_HEADER_MS-CV'='n18meLNAALDyuy32hSgFNA.0'
  'RESPONSE_HTTP_HEADER_CONTENT-TYPE'='application/xml;charset=utf-8'
  'RESPONSE_HTTP_HEADER_P3P'='CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"'
  'RESPONSE_HTTP_HEADER_X-FRAME-OPTIONS'='SAMEORIGIN'
  'RESPONSE_HTTP_HEADER_X-IDCRL_AUTH_PARAMS_V1'='IDCRL Type="BPOSIDCRL", EndPoint="/sites/<sitecollection>/_vti_bin/idcrl.svc/", RootDomain="sharepoint.com", Policy="MBI"'
  'RESPONSE_HTTP_HEADER_SERVER'='Microsoft-IIS/10.0'
  'RESPONSE_HTTP_HEADER_REQUEST-ID'='78265f9f-40b3-b000-f2bb-2df685280534'
  'RESPONSE_HTTP_HEADER_X-MS-INVOKEAPP'='1; RequireReadOnly'
  'RESPONSE_HTTP_HEADER_X-CONTENT-TYPE-OPTIONS'='nosniff'
  'RESPONSE_HTTP_HEADER_X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_REQUIRED'='https://<mytenant>.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=/_layouts/15/error.aspx&Source=%2f_vti_bin%2fclient.svc%2fweb%3f%24select%3dTitle'
  'RESPONSE_HTTP_STATUS'='403'
  'RESPONSE_HTTP_HEADER_DATASERVICEVERSION'='3.0'
```

I also tried it with different HTTP Headers, by using cookies and by skip them. Nothing works from middleware but everything from my PC.

Patrick

Answer (score 1):

You could try this way to get authentication：

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/access-sharepoint-online-rest-api-via-postman-with-user-context/

Answer (score 0):

I use some kind of middleware called "Lobster data". This is a software product to map data between different kind of systems. It's comparable to Microsoft BizTalk or others.

However this software uses some special prefix for HTTP header which I was not aware of. Thanks to their support team, I was able to overcome this issue.

Commonly, if you set a HTTP header, you simple use the name of the header you want to add like "content-type" or "authorization" and pass a value.

When using Lobster, you need to add "REQUEST_HTTP_HEADER_" as a prefix, so it needs to be "REQUEST_HTTP_HEADER_authorization" instead of just "authorization". Otherwise it will not send the data as a HTTP Header.

This is only true when using Lobster and not in general. I wasn't aware that they use this syntax.